# How do I run Console application function from frontend?

Tags: php, console, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to run the Console application send mail function from the frontend. I tried using [this](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension) extension but it isn't working.

```
namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;

/**
 * Console controller
 */
class ConsoleController extends  \yii\console\Controller
{
   public function actionSendMail()
   {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom('test@test1.com')
                ->setTo('test@test2.com')
                ->setSubject('Message subject')
                ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
                ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
                ->send();
   }
}
```

From command line I can use `yii console/send-mail` and it works fine.

But how can I run the above command in frontend controller?

Comment: How you run from frontend?

Comment: I tried console runner extesnion Yii::$app->consoleRunner->run('console/send-mail'); in my frontend site controller. But it does not work.

Comment: You set absolute path in `'file'` in components config? Path like `/var/www/domain/www/yii`

Comment: Yes I used the absolute path: 'file' => 'E:\wamp\www\demo\yii'

Answer (score 1):

Don't work, because https://github.com/vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension/blob/master/ConsoleRunner.php#L63 `PHP_BINDIR` in my computer value 'C\php'. But in my computer PHP not install in 'C\php' directory. You may:

1) Create 'C\php' folder and put `php.exe` into this directory.

2) Or add `PHP_BINDIR` variable in `Environment variables` (how that - http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) and put in your correct path to `php.exe`. And restart computer.

In my computer I run first step and run `Yii::$app->consoleRunner->run('hello/some-action')` in `SiteControler` and it is work fine.